# Lua - How to pass object's function as parameter to another function

Tags: callback, lua

```
local a = {}
function a:test1(value)
    print(value)
end
local b = {}
function b:test2(v1, v2)
    v2(100);
end
b:test2(_, a.test1)
```

Doesn't work. Value is nil. I could find a solution doing an encapsulation in an anonymous function

```
b:test2(variable, function(value) a:test1(value) end)
```

But I find it pretty bad mkay

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: Why are you not passing the object itself?

Comment: less flexible. this would mean b must do the call to the test1 function, thus limiting its usage to the a object

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`anotherObject:aFunction(variable, object.doStuff)` is the correct syntax.

Using a colon `:` with a function is just syntactic sugar for a call or declaration with an implicit `self` parameter as the first argument. If you would like to follow the pattern you've shown in your example in a cleaner way, you could use a helper function.

```
local function bind(t, k)
    return function(...) return t[k](t, ...) end
end
```

You then apply it like so.

```
anotherObject:aFunction(variable, bind(object, 'doStuff'))
```

---

**Edit:** I believe the solution to your problem will require binding at some level, without resorting to modifying the Lua interpreter or using a code translation step.
This is fundamentally because functions in Lua do not carry any information about their *origin*. **I.e.**, tables do not inherently *own* the functions that they *store*.

For example, the following is perfectly legitimate Lua code.

```
function Circle:area() -- function Circle.area(self)
    -- ...
end

-- Evaluate the function in the "area" slot with Square as the self parameter.
Circle.area(Square)
```

---

Of course, you could try a paradigm shift, but it may be too late for that if you're building an entire application based on the idea of functions being tied to the table that they have been indexed from, as you said.
Therefore, I propose the following **crazy** solution.

```
local mt = {}

function mt:__index(k)
    local v = self._slots[k]

    if v == nil then
        -- Ascend the inheritance tree.

        -- This has to be done with rawget all the way up,
        -- otherwise inherited functions would be repeatedly bound.
        local p = self

        repeat
            p = rawget(p, '_parent')
            if not p then break end
            v = p._slots[k]
        until v
    end

    if type(v) == 'function' then
        -- Return a self-bound version of the function.
        return function(...) return v(self, ...) end
    end

    return v
end

function mt:__newindex(k, v)
    self._slots[k] = v
end

--- Demo & Tests ---

local function Object(parent)
    local o = setmetatable({_slots = {}}, mt)
    if parent then rawset(o, '_parent', parent) end
    return o
end

local o1 = Object()
local o2 = Object(o1)

assert(o1.abc == nil, 'o1.abc should be nil')
o1.abc = 3
assert(o1.abc == 3, 'o1.abc should be 3')
assert(o2.abc == 3, 'o2.abc should be 3, inherited from o1')
o2.abc = 7
assert(o2.abc == 7, 'o2.abc should be 7, overriding o1')
assert(o1.abc == 3, 'o1.abc should be 3, unaffected by o2 setter')

function o1:test(bar)
    return self.abc + bar
end

assert(type(o1.test) == 'function', 'o1.test should be a function')
assert(type(o2.test) == 'function', 'o2.test should be a function, inherited from o1')

assert(o1.test(5) == 8, 'o1.test(5) should return 3 + 5 = 8')
assert(o2.test(11) == 18, 'o2.test(11) should return 7 + 11 = 18')

function o2:test2(fn)
    return self.abc + fn(7)
end

assert(o2.test2(o1.test) == 17, 'o2.test2(o1.test) should return 7 + (3 + 7) = 17')

o2.test3 = o1._slots.test -- proper function copying
assert(o2.test3(11) == 18, 'o2.test3(5) should return 7 + 11 = 18')

o2.abc = nil
assert(o2.abc == 3, 'o2.abc should be 3 again, inherited from o1 after clearing')

o2.abc = false
assert(o2.abc == false, 'o2.abc should be false, __index needs to differentiate between nil and false')
```

---

This metatable will provide you with what you want, with inherited and bound functions to boot. You will just need to make sure that all of the tables that you want to follow this pattern also follow the method of object creation shown in the example code.

To explain, each table made in this way has any new assignment redirected into the `_slots` sub-table and any new retrieval checked up the `_parent` inheritance tree. If the type of the value is a `function`, then it returns a new closure with the original `self` that started the check bound to the function found.

Obviously, calling a function from one of these objects with the `:` colon syntax is going to be a silly idea, since it would evaluate to `o.fn(o, o)`, and that is probably not what you want. Another caveat is that copying functions onto these objects, *from* these objects, will not work as expected. `o1.newfn = o2.fn` will put an `o2` bound function into `o1`, which in turn will be re-bound to `o1`. The end result would be something like `o2.fn(o2, o1)`. You will have to copy functions from the `_slots` table.

---

**In conclusion:** Even though this works, I would not personally recommend it in the long run, since it may be confusing to anyone used to how Lua works with tables, indexing, and functions, and there *will* be overhead. You might be able to do away with some it via [memoizing](http://www.lua.org/pil/17.1.html) the closures, but I'll leave that decision up to you. Good luck!

Comment: Althought your answer is great, and your way is probably cleaner, I have been building the whole application with an object oriented pattern which is based on lua manual : http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html (see bottom). Using a bind helper function would mean rewriting the whole stuff

Comment: @Rayjax I've updated my answer with a full solution. Please let me know what you think. As for the object oriented pattern shown in *Programming in Lua*, I don't believe there's anything in there referring to or encouraging the use of functions in the way that you want to use them. I hope I've clarified this with my answer.

Comment: As you said, your approach IS crazy, althought very interesting. I think that as I have built around 80% of my current project, I'll go on and finish with the pattern I've used. I know there are several ways of implementing OO programming in lua, in your opinion, what is the best one ?

Comment: @Rayjax As with a lot of things, it depends. It depends on what you're doing, what you need, and what you don't need. I usually start with the simplest structures and work from there. A variety of OO styles can be implemented in Lua, for sure. So I don't think there's any particular absolute best style. I would however have to say that I think using plain tables with prototype-based inheritance is the simplest OO style. Here's an [example](https://gist.github.com/RyanStein/7594612) of what I mean. Go with the flow and try not to fight against the language and what it provides.

Answer (score 1):

Object method declared with `:` needs object instance as the first parameter. It gets added automatically if you call it with `:`, but as you passed just a function pointer, you need to pass this as well. This means whenever you pass a function in some object somewhere, you also have to pass object instance. This works:

```
local a = {}
function a:test1(value)
    print(value)
end
local b = {}
function b:test2(obj, v2)
    v2(obj, 100);  -- object instance is always the first param of a ":"-style func
end
b:test2(a, a.test1) -- passing object instance and a function
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @ryan-stein's neat `bind()` solution, in a module I've found this to be slightly more concise:

```lua
local m = {}
m.__index = m
m.word = 'bar'

function m:bind(fn)
    return function(...) return self[fn](self, ...) end
end

function m:foo(fn)
    print("Foo " .. self.word)
end

function m:start()
    hs.timer.new(42, self:bind('foo'))
end
```

Answer (score -1):

your code will be work. the reason Ryan has said.
I doubt that in the function anotherObject:aFunction(), you were using a wrong way to call the object.stuff.The correct way as this:

```
local a = {}
function a:test1()
    print(1)
end
local b = {}
function b:test2(v1, v2)
    v2();
end
b:test2(_, a.test1)
```

Comment: Your function works because a:test1 doesn't receive any parameter.
Look with a parameter - prints nil
local a = {}
function a:test1(value)
    print(value)
end
local b = {}
function b:test2(v1, v2)
    v2(100);
end
b:test2(_, a.test1)